How do I use a react-web-component component in a vanilla js file tied to an HTML file
I created a simple React component.
const ReactComponent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("something");
  return <div>Hello {name}</div>
}
export default ReactComponent;

And I used react-to-webcomponent library to convert it to a plain HTML tag which gives me  tags which I can use in any page. But I want to use it inside a standalone HTML page with vanilla js.
index.html
<script async defer src='index.js'></script>
<body>
  <div id='main>Hello World</div>
</body>

index.js
import {initComponent} from '/ReactComponentWC.js'

const main = document.getElementById("main");
initComponent(main)

In ReactComponentWC.js
const initComponent = (containerElement) => {
    const reactElement = r2wc(ReactComponent, React, ReactDOM)
    customElements.define("react-component", reactElement)
    const myComp = document.createElement('div')
    myComp.innerHTML = `<react-component />`
    containerElement.appendChild(myComp)
}

export { initComponent }

When I load index.html using Live Server, I encounter this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'react'. Relative references must start with either '/', './', or '../'."
I then tried bundling the ReactComponentWC.js file using Webpack. However, when I imported from the bundled /dist/ReactComponent.js file, it showed the error:
"No export named 'initComponent' found."
This import works fine in any Next.js page in my app, but the error only occurs in this standalone HTML page.
Any suggestions on how I can export my React component so that it can be used by any JS frontend framework or even vanilla JS apps? Thanks in advance!
